# Spring Boot interceptor not called with custom handler mapping/adapter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot 2 project I use a simple interceptor that was working fine. However after creating a custom `HandlerAdapter` and `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` the interceptor never executed again.

```
public class RequestMonitoringInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        logger.debug("preHandle");      

        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    ...

}
```

And registered in my `WebConfig` as:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public RequestMonitoringInterceptor requestMonitoringInterceptor() {
        return new RequestMonitoringInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestMonitoringInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Any idea what I have missed?

Comment: Because you aren't setting the `interceptors` on the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`.

Comment: Yes, really that was the problem! Thanks (again)!